# Windows Server 2012 MSMQ - Some Clients don't connect

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, msmq

We have some strange things happening with a new installation of MSMQ on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Cluster:

- the clients reach the server without problems
- the server tries to send a message to the client and gets the error message "Failed to connect to winsock socket"
- the server is able to ping the client and vice versa
- restarting the MSMQ-Client on the clients (Windows 7 domain-members, same domain as the server) seems to fix the problem teporarily
- it only affects a few clients, and not always the same. We might have identified one of the reasons being that the network is not fully operational at the time the MQ-client starts. Starting the client without network connection always results in the error.
- the strangest thing: it only affect communication to the new 2012-server. The same clients have no problems communicating with MSMQ on 2008-servers, even when they can't communicate with the 2012 MQ at the same time.

One articel we found described opening the firewallports for RPC-EPMAP, which we did, unfortunatelly without helping. The log of the firewall shows no dropped packets.

At the moment we are clueless, especially since the Clients just work flawlessly with the Windows 2008 MSMQ-Servers.

Comment: The error "Failed to connect to winsock socket" doesn't sound right. Are you sending from server TO a queue on the client or is the client receiving FROM a queue on the server?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is displayed in the MSMQ managementconsole (Services and Applications/Message Queuing). There are no eventlogs generated on the server for errors. 
The problem is with the communication fom the server back to the client. The client reaches the server, but the answer doesn't get to the client. It can be reproduced by starting the client without network connection and establishing the connection after the login. Restarting the MSMQ-client solves this. Communication with the 2008 MSMQ-server isn't affected at all, works even while not recieving from the 2012 MSMQ.

Comment: Hi Marco, please take a look at [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/201151)

Comment: I still don't understand the message flow. 
"the clients reach the server without problems" - is this a message being sent successfully from a client to a queue on the server?
"but the answer doesn't get to the client." - is this an acknowledgement message generated by MSMQ or an application message generated by an app on the server?

Comment: "it only affects a few clients, and not always the same." - are these clients cloned from a standard build or installed from scratch?